# Should I ask programming questions on Stack Overflow or on the "Programmers" Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Title says it all.

Does it matter where I ask it? Is there a way to have one question post to both sites?

Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousands of programming questions asked on SO every day (maybe more?).

The programmers one is just more focused. There are many different sites in the Stack Exchange network. Look through the questions on the programming one (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and just see where you think your questions will be best answered. I am active in both but 99% of my questions end up here on SO.

Comment: Did you move my question?